# php/iis: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, windows, iis, fopen

I am trying to do this:

```
$fh = fopen("req2" , 'w')
```

and I get:

> Warning: fopen(D:\inetpub\wwwroot\req2) [function.fopen]: failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line
>   44 can't open file

I gave "Full Control" permissions to IIS in the wwwroot directory. I had also tried the absolute path: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\\req2"`

but i still get the same error. I am running IIS 7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Use [Process Monitor](http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe) to see which user is actually trying to access the file.

Comment: Please have a look onto [http://forums.iis.net/t/1167645.aspx](http://forums.iis.net/t/1167645.aspx) Also see this [http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/)

Comment: thanks! solved. it was me who didn't have permissions to write :P

Comment: Try giving full control to all users, if it works then revert back access control one by one and you'd see which user was creating issue

Answer (score 13):

In Windows, you need to give user, `IUSR` the permission.

Comment: You also need the file to not be marked as "Read Only"

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

> Right click folder --> Properties --> Security --> Edit --> allow Full Control --> apply --> do this for all, or just the correct user

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you run into this with downloaded code, make sure that you have "unblocked" it to run locally.

File encryption must also be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Got this today on Windows 10 after I shared the wwwroot folder. Was working before that. Had to take the sharing off and reapply iis_iusr access permissions.